# CNN unbalanced and small dataset

Tags: deep-learning, keras, class-imbalance

I would like to use CNN to make classification with 5 classes, but 4 of these classes only have between 16 and 60 images, while the last one has more than 1300. I know 16 or 60 images are not enough, so I want to use transfer learning, fine tuning and data augmentation. However, I have several questions.

As the data augmentation must only be used for the training data, I will have very few images from the 4 classes for the validation set, would it be a problem?

Is it needed to split it in training/validation/test, or is training/validation enough?

Another problem is the unbalanced data: with such a difference between the number of images in each class, would oversampling or undersampling be a good solution?

For transfer learning and fine tuning, should I freeze all the convolutional layers or should I only train a FC layer?

Comment: Why is the class imbalance a problem for you?

Answer (score 1):

> As the data augmentation must only be used for the training data, I will have very few images from the 4 classes for the validation set, would it be a problem?

You may first perform data augmentation on the image dataset and then split it into train/test or train/test/validation. Just make sure that the images present in the test split are not included in the training split or vice-versa. See [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-configure-image-data-augmentation-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/).

> Is it needed to split it in training/validation/test, or is training/validation enough ?

The validation dataset is particularly to fine-tune the model's hyperparameters i.e for hyperparameter optimization. If you want to simply skip that procedure, just make two splits, train, and test. See [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/evaluate-performance-deep-learning-models-keras).

See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set) answer to know the difference between test and validation dataset.

> Another problem is the unbalanced data with such a difference
> between the number of images in each class, would oversampling or
> undersampling be a good solution ?

I would encourage you to augment the images for a specific class until you are left with a near-balanced dataset.

> For transfer learning and fine tuning, should I freeze all the convolutional layers or should I only train a FC layer?

As a common practice, you may try **unfreezing** some initial layers ( layers that usually have lesser filters ). Refer to [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/transfer-learning-for-deep-learning) blog. Deeper layers have more filters and extract high-level features.

Comment: Thank you ! 
Should I use data augmentation only for classes having few images ? Or should I oversample these classes and then use data augmentation (which would lead to the same images horizontally flipped several times, for example) ?

Comment: Use data augmentation for the class having fewer images. Oversampling and then data augmentation won't work, as you might have identical samples in your training dataset.